# React native upgrade: TypeError: Object is not a constructor (evaluating 'new _reactNative.TextInput()')

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to update my react-native from version 0.61.4 to 0.66.4. But, for some reason I'm getting the following error:

TypeError: Object is not a constructor (evaluating 'new _reactNative.TextInput()')

There is my package.json:

```
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "^0.66.4",

"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "git-commit-msg-linter": "^2.4.4",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.6",
    "metro": "0.64.0",
    "metro-config": "0.64.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  }
```

Can someone help me here? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Did you follow [these steps](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.61.4&to=0.66.4)?

Comment: Hello Abe, I used this steps but they generated the error above :(

Comment: Is this a big project?  A good workaround can be to start a new project and drop in your components.

Comment: Unfortunately yes! I can't start it again :(

Comment: You don't have to start over, you can make a new project, manually add in your dependencies in package.json, and paste in all your custom files.  It's a pain, but it should get you working again.

Comment: I just figured out what was going on. I needed to update some libraries! Now it is working perfectly!

Comment: Yay!  Nice work.

Comment: @fernandofincatti dear fernando, can you tell me which packages did you update?